# Как подключить бд к консольному приложению без GUI

Tags: c++, консоль

[image: вывод программы]

/* Вот фрагмент кода программы, подскажите пожалуйста как именно можно реализовать эту идею, подключения БД к данному приложению, чтобы после ввода, данные отправлялись в БД, просто нигде не могу найти это, а работать с txt файлами как альтернатива БД ну такое. Заранее спасибо */

```
int main()
```

{

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
system("title ConsoleOS");

std::string log;
std::string pass;

std::cout << "Логин: ";
std::cin >> log;
std::cout << "Пароль: ";
std::cin >> pass;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: К какой конкретно БД? К каждой по-своему, да и работа с разными БД тоже реализуется по-разному. БД "вообще" — это как тот пресловутый сферический конь в вакууме...

Comment: к любой базе данных 
MySQL, Ms Access, Ms SQL Server
к какой проще и вообще возможно ли это

Comment: Конечно, возможно. Раз хотите SQL — hекомендую [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), это попроще... Как именно подключаться и работать — смотрите по ссылке, писать за вас полный готовый код никто не будет...

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендацию)))
Готового кода я и не ждал), самому хочется разбираться на глубоком уровне